# Vue.js Import Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vue-cli

I'm facing a problem with importing Objects from the App.vue file to a component. But first I should explain the purpose of this project.
There's a component (navigation-drawer) and an App.vue file. The Navigation drawer has vue props in it, which you can dynamically change in the App.vue file. The problem with that is that I can only use as many links as there are in the Navigation-Drawer file.

I would like to edit it so I can use as many links as I need, without even having to open the Navigation-Drawer.vue file. Before I go into more detail, here are the files with the props & limited amount of links:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <navigation-drawer
    name1="TFBern"
    name2="Stackoverflow"
    name3="YouTube"
    name4="Google"
    link1="https://vuejs.org"
    link2="https://stackoverflow.com"
    link3="https://youtube.com"
    link4="https://google.com"
    />

    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
  import NavigationDrawer from './components/Navigation-Drawer.vue'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      HelloWorld,
      NavigationDrawer
      }
    }
</script>
```

**Navigation-Drawer.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="navigationdrawer">
        <span @click="openNav" style="fontsize:30px;cursor:pointer;display:flex;justify-content:center;">&#9776;</span>
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" @click="closeNav">&times;</a>
            <a v-bind:href="link1">{{ name1 }}</a>
            <a v-bind:href="link2">{{ name2 }}</a>
            <a v-bind:href="link3">{{ name3 }}</a>
            <a v-bind:href="link4">{{ name4 }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'NavigationDrawer',
    props: {
        name1: String,
        name2: String,
        name3: String,
        name4: String,
        link1: String,
        link2: String,
        link3: String,
        link4: String
 },

 methods: {
     openNav() {
         document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '15%'
         },

    closeNav() {
        document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '0%'
        }
    }
 }

</script>
```

Now, what I had in mind was to create a js object, which can import the links from App.vue into the Drawer. Something like this:

```
<navigation-drawer links="[ {title="Google", link="www.google.ch"} , {title="Youtube", link="www.youtube.com"} , {title=…, link=…} ]"
```

I don't really know how to do it... Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close to the answer already. Change `=` to `:`, the values to be surrounded with `'` instead of `"` so you have a list of objects

```
<navigation-drawer v-bind:links="[ {title:'Google', link:'www.google.ch'} , {title:'Youtube', link:'www.youtube.com'} , {title:…, link:…} ]"
```

Then the navigation-drawer props look like:

```
props: {
    links: Array
},
```

and the html loops through the links with a `v-for` and [template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt):

```
<div class="navigationdrawer">
    <span @click="openNav" style="fontsize:30px;cursor:pointer;display:flex;justify-content:center;">&#9776;</span>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" @click="closeNav">&times;</a>
        <template v-for=v-for="(link, index) in links">
            <a v-bind:href="link.link"  :key="index">{{ link.title}}</a>
        </template>
    </div>
</div>
```